# Why does this non-negative term exclude zero as an option?

Tags: inequality

On a past paper I have stumbled upon a question which I do not agree with. The question states that *a* is a positive number and that *b* is "non-negative" and presents 4 different answers.

[The multiple choice answers](https://i.stack.imgur.com/X3kt7.png)

I believe that *b≥0*. However its not listed as an answer. Correct answer is *b>0* but that would exclude when *b=o*.

Can someone confirm if the paper is wrong or if there's something I missed.

For those asking for the question: It's in Swedish but translates: a is positive and b is non-negative. Given that exactly one of these four statements are true, which one is it?

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: I've added the question and altered the title, thank you for the advice.

Comment: The key is that it says that **exactly** one of the options is true.

Comment: Welcome to MathStackExchange! Please avoid posting pictures to question statements. Rather than this, edit your question to contain in text what you posted as a picture (in english). This is good practice for the maintainability and future use of this site.

Comment: positive and non negative mean the same thing

Comment: what is the need of defining 'a' when you are comparing b with '0'

Comment: @sawankumawat I would argue that 0 is not positive and therefore non-negative includes 0 (b≥0). To answer your other question, a is defined in case of the right answer being a comparison between a and b, which is not the case.

Comment: @sawankumawat, no, they are different. "Non-negative" allows for the possibility of being equal to $0$.

Comment: @BarryCipra Would you care to explain why the answer "b>0" could be interpreted as correct even though its clear that a non-negative number allows for the possibility of being equal to 0?

Comment: @AlexanderStroborg, I just fleshed it out as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a cute little exercise in logic. The problem is asserting three things:

(1) $a\gt0$

(2) $b\ge0$

(3) **exactly one** of the following is true: (a) $b=0$; (b) $b\gt a$; (c) $b\lt a$; or (d) $b\gt0$

The key is the word "exactly." From $b\ge0$, we know that either $b=0$ or $b\gt0$, so either (a) or (d) must be true. This rules out (b) and (c), which means we actually have $b=a$. From $a\gt0$, we now conclude that $b\gt0$ is the one correct choice, given that we've been told there is exactly one true statement in (3).

Comment: What a beautiful way of solving it. I noticed a typo "so either (a) or (b) must be true". I assume you meant to say "so either (a) or (d) must be true."

Comment: @AlexanderStroborg, thanks, fixed!

Answer (score 0):

Defining $b$ as non negative number opens the possibility of $b$ being zero. Also since $a$ is given as a positive number, then it can't be zero.
so using above two conclusions $a \ge b$ and $b\ge 0$ . so the given option is wrong and you are right.

Comment: As much as I'd like to believe I am correct, @BarryCipra provided an excellent explanation. I would read it and reconsider your answer.